# How could a rechargeable battery charge itself without an external source?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, energy, battery-chemistry

While I was working on my graduation project I had  to charge a rechargeable battery then discharge it and so on.I was shocked when the battery charged itself without any other external sources for many times immediately when it died! 
Any explanations please ?

Comment: How deep are you discharging it?  It could be the battery management software is getting to know the battery and becoming more accurate in its reporting.

Answer (score 4):

The chemical processes that happen inside a battery when it is being discharged take time to occur - if they cannot keep up with the load on the battery the voltage will drop and it will be seen as dead. One name for this is polarization.

If the battery is left for some time the chemical processes can catch up and you can then discharge the battery again until it is discharged.

Usually the time for subsequent discharges will be shorter and shorter until the battery is really dead.

The speed of chemical processes happen faster at higher temperatures so warming up the battery can provide more output before the battery output collapses and recover more quickly.

Answer (score 3):

A "dead" battery simply means that it cannot deliver enough voltage and current to the load in order to operate it. In order to understand how a battery can have enough voltage but still not be able to deliver it, we need to understand what a battery is.

Every battery can be modeled as an ideal voltage source and an internal resistance. As current flows through the internal resistance, a voltage drop builds across it. Thanks to Ohm's law, we know that the more current drawn the higher the voltage drop.

A DMM with its input impedance of 10Mohm draws almost no current, hence there is very little voltage drop and we measure almost the exact voltage available from the voltage source. A flashlight on the other hand presents a much smaller impedance. Therefore a battery that measures X volts on the DMM will deliver much less than X volts to the flashlight, causing it to be very dim or to not light at all. What's more, as batteries drain or age their internal resistance often *increases*, making the problem even worse.